# Swift how to calculate value once and share it across the whole app

Tags: ios, swift, variables, global-variables, global

I am working on an app that has been worked on by several developers over the last 3 years and it's hard to follow. There is a value calculated in one module (core.swift) that I want to use in several of the other view controllers in the app. The previous devs seem to have re-calculated it in every view controller, but that has introduced errors b/c their calc are slightly different.

How can I share this across all VCs so I can add it to a label and show that value?

I have looked into global variables but don't really understand if I need to change the current code to add Struct and what the impact of that will be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it static and define it in a public/global scope

Comment: Example sample please to  show how special the case

Answer (score -1):

The best thing is to use Singleton design pattern, this is how it works:

```
class SharedInstance {
    private init(){}
    static let sharedInstance = SharedInstance()
    var calcule = 0
}
```

The way you will use it:

```
SharedInstance.sharedInstance.calcule = 5
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help - will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks very much - will give it a try.